# C# Error: "A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods"

Tags: c#

A method receiving 2 numbers and I need to return the numbers of common digits for them. For example, the numbers `2201` and `3021` returns `3` because these numbers have 3 common digits: 0, 1, and 2.

I get this error and don't understand it: `A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods`

Here is the code:

```
public static int AlphaRomeo(int a, int b)
{
    int count = 0;
    while (a > 0)
    {
        int tempa = a % 10;
        a = a / 10;
        int tempb = b % 10;
        b = b / 10;
        if (tempa == tempb)
            count++;
    }
    return count;

}
```

[image: The screen shot]

Comment: Can you show the whole file. That error usually happens when adding a property/method directly directly within a namespace when it requires that it is places within another construct (usually a class.)

Comment: Yes! I will edit it into the thread.

Comment: What class/struct does your method belong to?

Comment: No pictures of code ever please. You need to put this method within a class, the class goes within the namespace. You cannot define methods directly in a namespace.

Comment: @greenjaed, I am honestly don't know what do you mean by  class/struct

Comment: @OmarAbdelBari So do you suggest me to write ConsoleApp14 instead of AlphaRomeo?

Comment: CTRL+F "SampleClass" in this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/namespaces/ Object Oriented Languages are centered around classes which represent objects. Hence they don't like it when you put methods and other members outside of a general construct like a `class`

Comment: Thanks! it really helped!

Comment: @OmarAbdelBari, not so true anymore ;)

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils I used `classes` to keep it simple. But you can say constructs. Does that mean they don't deviate from OOP? Of course not. But here's an example where they put a firm foot down and said NO

Answer (score 0):

Might be easier to avoid the mathematics:

```
private static string _digits = "0123456789";

public static int AlphaRomeo(int a, int b)
{
    string aStr = a.ToString();
    string bStr = b.ToString();
    int common = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < _digits.Length; i++)
    {
        if (aStr.Contains(_digits[i]) && bStr.Contains(_digits[i]))
            common++;
    }

    return common;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Consider this example, you don't have a class in your code:

```cs
using System;  // Imports

namespace LearnClasses    // Namespace
{
    class Program    //class
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)   // Method 1
        {
           Console.WriteLine( AlphaRomeo(2201, 3021));
        }

        public static int AlphaRomeo(int a, int b)  // Method 2
        {
            int count = 0;
            // Your code
            return count;
        }
    }
}
```